Django Bootstrap form-select...how do I find the selected value?
I have a Django application using Bootstrap form-select. This is filled up from a table like this:
<div class="div-1 rounded bg-light text-dark ">
  {% trans "Active restaurant: " %}
  <select class="form-select-sm bg-light text-dark" aria-label={% trans "Select a restaurant" %} id="Selected_Restarurant">
    <option selected>{% trans "Select a restaurant" %}</option>
      {% for restaurant in restaurants %}
          <option value="restaurant.name">{{ restaurant.name }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>


I have no idea how to address the value selected by the user in the form-select above. I need to run a filter on employee and update an employee table in the home.html template below to only show the employees of the selected restaurant. I know it has to do with the model and filters, that is also well documented, but how do I find the selected value and update the table below based on the selection?:
<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <thead class="table-success">
        <tr>
            <!--th scope="col">{% trans "Employees" %}</th-->
            <th scope="col">{% trans "Restaurant" %}</th>
            <th scope="col">{% trans "First name" %}</th>
            <th scope="col">{% trans "Last name" %}</th>
            <th scope="col">{% trans "Username" %}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-group-divider">
        {% for employee in employees %}
            {% if employee.restaurant.name == "McDonalds in the bush" %}
                <tr>
                    <!--td>{{ employee.user.first_name }}</td-->
                    <td>{{ employee.restaurant.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.user.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.user.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.user.username }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>



1)Load all the restaurents in HTML not recomended if the list is huge.
What you are doing is using django templating engine to build html page
so. in this approach I am loading all the restaurants in HTML and using java script jquery to manipulate genrated html using selector like id.
first hide all the lines which u dont want to show. and later when a user selects an option just unhide the required output
load this to bottom of you html
<script>
    $('#Selected_Restarurant').change(function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var restaurntList = [{% for restaurant in restaurants %}
                            '{{restaurant.name}}',
                                {%endfor%}];

    // Loop through restaurantList to check if selectedValue exists
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < restaurantList.length; i++) { 
        if (selectedValue===restaurantList[i]) 
        { found=true; 
            break; } 
        }; 
        
        
    if(found) {
        // Show the selected table row 
         $("#" + selectedValue).show(); 
         // Hide all other table rows 
         $("tr").not("#"+ selectedValue).hide(); 
        } 
    else { 
        // If selectedValue is not found, show all table rows 
        $("tr").show(); 
    } });

Make sure all the restarurants are loded with id of each restarurants in tr

    {% for employee in employees %}
            
                <tr id="{{ employee.restaurant.name }}">
                    <!--td>{{ employee.user.first_name }}</td-->
                    <td>{{ employee.restaurant.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.user.first_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.user.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.user.username }}</td>
                </tr>
            
        {% endfor %}


On each change in selected value you can run an XHR request to the server to get the employee's details making an additional view.
you can just chatgpt on how to fetch the data and update the table
if you need guide drop a comment


Please explain the answer above. This does not make sense to me as a windows programmer. Your solution, if I understand correctly, is basically this:
//Store selected value (restaurant name or "Select restaurant") in a variable
//Go through all the restaurants to make a list of their names (again)
//Go through this list of names to find the selected value (and again)
//    if found then: show the selected row in the table of employees
//    else: hide it
Isn't this double work done unnecessary?

What i have not explained is very basics so i thought it is not necessary to explain.let me edit the answer.

Sujay: Am i correct in that this loops through the restaurant list two times for every time the user makes a selection?
